# 'incomplete type is not allowed' when using struct defined in the header file as a function parameter

Tags: c++, struct

I just switched from Python to C++. This is a practice I did for `struct`. There's always an error 'incomplete type is not allowed' if I don't directly use struct at the source file.

I have review many answers at stack overflow and tried to add `typedef` in header or remove struct at `std::vector<double> timesteps(struct temporal_info time)`, but none of them work.

Here's my dmdbase.h

```
#ifndef dmdbase
#define dmdbase

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class DMDBase

{
public:
    struct temporal_info
    {
        double t0;
        int trend;
        double dt;
    };
    std::vector<double> timesteps(struct temporal_info time);
};
#endif
```

Here's my dmdbase.cpp

```
using namespace std;


std::vector<double> timesteps(struct temporal_info time)
{
    std::vector<double> time_map;
    double final = time.trend + time.dt;
    for (double t = time.t0; t < final; t += time.dt)
    {
        time_map.push_back(t);
    }
    return time_map;
}
```

Comment: The answers of benroberts999 and andnik should solve your problem. However, you should favor andnik's answer, since he put the `DMDBase::` in the correct place.  Another hint: Don't get used to `using namespace std`. It might get you into trouble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Since benroberts999 corrected his answer, forget what I said about which answer to favor. ;)

Comment: @wychmaster you can erase your comments that have became incorrect after edits instead of correcting them with more comments. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the struct keyword in the function call site, that is not part of the type

```
std::vector<double> timesteps(temporal_info time);
```

Also: Issue is struct 'temporal_info' only defined inside the DMDBase class.
So you have to do this

```
std::vector<double> DMDBase::timesteps(temporal_info time);
```

Comment: Your answer solved this problem. I had spent hours on this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

In `dmdbase.cpp` make sure you specify that `timesteps` is a method of `DMDBase` class.
And remove `struct` keyword before `temporal_info` as it was already mentioned.

```
std::vector<double> DMDBase::timesteps(temporal_info time)
{
    ...
}
```

The emphasis is on `DMDBase::timesteps`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your post answer solved this problem.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


typedef struct temporal_info temporal_info;

class DMDBase

{
public:
    struct temporal_info
    {
        double t0;
        int trend;
        double dt;
    };
    std::vector<double> timesteps(temporal_info time);
};
```

Comment: This is not C, no need for `typedef struct`.